# Matplotlib: last y tick label not visible with 0 margins

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a cdf, where I want the y tick labels to be 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.
Here's how I'm achieving it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# some code

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 5))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.around(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.2),1))
plt.margins(0)
...
plt.show()
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

When I comment out `plt.margins(0)`, I get the following figure:

[image]

Why am I not able to see the top most y tick label (1.0) in the first figure? How can I achieve it with 0 margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data ranges from 0 to 1. It will plot 1 in the top left corner.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.linspace(0,1,50)

plt.plot(data)
plt.margins(0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If your data does not range up to 1, it won't.

Same code with `data = np.linspace(0,0.99,50)` produces

[image]

So you need to set the limits manually to whatever range you want, because matplotlib cannot guess for you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.linspace(0,0.99,50)

plt.plot(data)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]